# Compiz not doing anything

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

I am trying to get the launcher icons to be a smaller size, the launcher to be less opaque, and the launcher to be fixed and never disappear off the left of the screen.

But...when I go into Compiz-->Ubuntu Unity Plugin (enabled)-->Experimental move the "Panel Opacity" and "Launcher Icon Size" icons left and right doesn't do anything.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The Launcher icon size can be changed diretly from System Settings >> Appearance.

Answer (score 1):

1. After changing the options in Compiz, logout the system and login again to make the changes.
2. Or you can use [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) which does the same things and which is very much reliable.